# How to produce this html table in asp.net?

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table, asp-classic

I need to convert a **classic asp app to asp.net**.
The old asp uses a *hardcoded html table* to get the results.
I am unsure how to get the same in .Net.

I need to produce a **grid** like look.

```
Section Heading

Name:P Smith
Address: 12 The road
Age: 22

New Section Heading

Job num: 24
Dept: Sales

New Section Heading

Insurance num: 93939
Next of kin: J Smith
```

Each section has a seperate dataset using it's own stored procedure.
One record is returned from each dataset for each section.

I tried a **repeater** and a **details list control**, but was unable to get the look required.

Any help & code appreciated.

Comment: use a formview. and then use a sql(or any connection)datasource and bind it

Comment: or a normal GridView and connect there you data source

Comment: Try this with repeater control, use dataset to hold multiple tables for different sections bit of UI work as well.

Comment: But how do you get seperate headings in the repeater control for each section?

Answer (score 2):

You need three different controls with three different bindings. Then you would have it render into a single HTML table, if that's what you want to do. Repeater should work well since you can control the HTML pretty well with a repeater. Roughly...

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater ...>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <tr><th colspan="2">Section Heading</th></tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            </tr><td>Name</td> <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Name")%></td></tr>
            // etc...
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

    <asp:Repeater ...>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <tr><th colspan="2">Section Heading</th></tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr><td>Name</td> <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Name")%></td></tr>
            // etc...
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

    // Repeat using repeaters and outputting rows and then close the table tag.

</table>
```

Then you can style your TH cells however you want to distinguish them from the TD cells.

Comment: I was thinking of that, but I wondered if I had say 6 repeaters in the 1 webform it may slow the page.

Comment: I think by combining multiple data sources the way you're doing, the repeaters themselves won't be what's slowing down your page. If the data is related and one row each, you would be better off combining and flattening the data on the SQL side in a single sproc, and then have a single bound formview. That would be the most efficient way to handle that type of data.

Comment: Thanks - is it possible to use conditions in a repeater. In the old asp they used  <td class="tablecell01a" width="70%">
    <%If rsProperty("startDate") AND rsProperty("EndDate") <>"NULL" Then%>
     <%=rsProperty("StartDate")%>&nbsp;to&nbsp;<%=rsProperty("EndDate")%>
     <%Else%>
    <%End If%>
   </td>

Comment: Google revealed >[this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1118304.aspx)< for conditional displays. Looks like if statements are allowed.

Comment: It works, but one thing I am finding is if I switch to design view the repeater rows are doubling up.